# Jquery Disabling individual buttons within search results that all have the same classes applied

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you take a look at: http://www.thebullionstore.co.uk/_shop/?_cat=9

You will see a list of products each wrapped in a div with the class product_box. Inside product_box there several other divs and a form with an add to cart button. inside the form there is a hidden input field called stock_amount with a value, the value attribute is the amount of each product that is in stock. Iv also added a number base to the stock_amount class name to distinguish each product listing such as stock_amount0, stock_amount1 ans so on.

I want to be able to disable each button for each individual product after a certain amount of clicks. The amount of clicks will be equal to the value of stock_amount so in-effect a user cant add more products to the cart than is available.

Adding to the cart is currently done with Jquery but I don't know jquery well enough to figure out how to loop through each product listing and do what I described above.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("button.addtocart").click(function(e) {
    // fetch <input name='stock_amount'> within the clicked buttons form element
    var stock_amount_input = $("input[name='stock_amount']", $(this).parent());
    // fetch <input name='_qty'> within the clicked buttons form element
    var qty_input = $("input[name='_qty']", $(this).parent());
    // maybe you want to do some check here
    var new_amount = stock_amount_input.val() - qty_input.val();
    // set the new calculated value in the stock_amount input
    stock_amount_input.val(new_amount);

    // if the new_amount is less than 1 we dissable the clicked button
    if(new_amount < 1) {
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thats works!! Not sure I quite understand exactly how its working can you talk me through it a bit?

Comment: Thanks I see what your doing now. Slightly different approach logically than what I thinking about. Your way is better ;)

Comment: Why doesn't this work as a check to see if the entered amount exceeds the stock amount : if(qty_input > stock_amount_input){qty_input.val(stock_amount_input);}

Comment: qty_input and stock_amount_input are the input elements itself. If you want to compare the value's you should change them to qty.input.val() and stock_amount_input.val()

Answer (score 0):

To loop thorough elements you can use the [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). Or write something like this:

```
var nodes = $("form");
for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
    var node = nodes[i];
    // do something
}
```

But I don't think you need to do this. You can preform the check and the disabling of the button in the click-event-handler. Furthermore you shouldn't forget to check if the entered amount (e.g. 1000) doesn't exceed the stock amount.